# BCP Export from SQL to CSV File, Metadata, Header Row

Tags: sql, csv, metadata, bcp

I need to export data from an SQL table to CSV format. But I also need:
1. Metadata inserted in the first row of the output. This will be static.
2. Header row after the metadata.
3. Data. BUT I need fields with multiple values (e.g. name JOHN SMITH) to be in "" and commas within the quotes to separate the values within the field.

Here is my first draft to get data in CSV:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT ITN_USER, SITE_ID, TICKET_NUMBER, VALIDATING_CARRIER_CODE, TICKET_EXPIRATION_DATE, TICKET_CURR_CODE, RESIDUAL_TOTAL_AMT, TICKET_TOTAL_FARE, PASSENGER_NAME, FIRST_ORIG_APT_CODE, FIRST_DEST_APT_CODE, FIRST_DEPART_DATE, TICKET_ISSUE_DATE, CRS_LOCATOR, TICKET_STATUS_ID, TICKET_TYPE, RSVN_SYS_ID, TICKETING_LOCATION, TICKET_BASE_FARE, TICKET_TAX, FARE_CALC_LINE FROM GDSX.dbo.UnusedTickets WHERE INSERT_DATE = ''01-31-2018''" queryout "C:\Users\Public\Documents\filename1_filename2_date.csv" /c /t, -T'
```

Any helpful tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I want to achieve: “josh@gmail.com,vbear@gmail.com"
ITN_USER,SITE_ID,TICKET_NUMBER,VALIDATING_CARRIER_CODE,TICKET_ EXPIRATION_DATE,TICKET_CURR_CODE,RESIDUAL_TOTAL_AMT,TICKET_TOT AL_FARE,PASSENGER_NAME,FIRST_ORIG_APT_CODE,FIRST_DEST_APT_CODE ,FIRST_DEPART_DATE,TICKET_ISSUE_DATE,CRS_LOCATOR,TICKET_STATUS _ID,TICKET_TYPE,RSVN_SYS_ID,TICKETING_LOCATION,TICKET_BASE_FAR E,TICKET_TAX,FARE_CALC_LINE vbear,abccorpus,0017845439769,AA,08MAY2009,USD,1226.57,1629.00 ,bear/vernon,MSY,ORD,17MAY2008,08MAY2008,,,electronic,,,,, jsmith,abccorpus,0167846739059,UA,19JUN2009,USD,354.00,354.00, smith/john,LAX,PDX,25JUN2008,19JUN2008,,,,,,,, dgarcia,abccorpmx,1327959759566,MX,03AUG2009,MXN,6828.06,6828. 06,garcia/diego,MEX,GUA,07AUG2008,03AUG2008,,,electronic,,,,,

Thanks!

Comment: Is this something you only have to do once?

Comment: Nope. I'll be using as much as each day. But likely just a few times a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Creating a view and use the view in your BCP statement. You can do all your calculation in the view. For metadata you need to do a union all with the data. SO your view will be something like...

```
Create view abc as 
   select 'Name' as Name, 'Age' as Age --Metadata 
      Union All
   Select Name , Cast(Age as Varchar(X)) from your table
```

make sure you give cast varchar for all the column as you will be doing union.

Comment: what makes you so sure the metadata will be column headers?

Comment: I'm getting an error with that. @Dan Bracuk you're right. The column headers need to be included but are not the metadata.

Comment: I did this:

CREATE VIEW UnusedTicketsExport AS 
SELECT 'ITN_USER' as ITN_USER, 'SITE_ID' as SITE_ID…
UNION ALL
SELECT ITN_USER Cast(ITN_USER as CHAR(40), SITE_ID Cast(SITE_ID as CHAR(100)…FROM UnusedTickets WHERE INSERT_DATE = '01-31-2018'

I get this error:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure UnusedTicketsExport, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: Yes it will add header only and same way we can add metadata as we know what datatype its going to return.   @josh- Not able to see your full script to understand. I would suggest to test this with 1 or 2 column first.

Comment: I get the same error. Here is what I ran:
CREATE VIEW UnusedTicketsExport AS 
SELECT 'ITN_USER' as ITN_USER, 'SITE_ID' as SITE_ID, 'TICKET_NUMBER' as TICKET_NUMBER -- Header
UNION ALL
SELECT ITN_USER Cast(ITN_USER as CHAR(40), SITE_ID Cast(SITE_ID as CHAR(100), TICKET_NUMBER Cast(TICKET_NUMBER as VARCHAR(25) FROM UnusedTickets

This is on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I guess you are missing one ")" after every conversion ?Cast(ITN_USER as CHAR(40)).

Comment: It was the format of the cast...Cast(ITN_USER as CHAR(40)) ITN_USER not ITN_USER Cast(ITN_USER as CHAR(40). It works now. Thanks. Is there a way to include the metadata to in the first row? Specifically  “josh@gmail.com,vbear@gmail.com"

Comment: If this is hardcoded value you can add another select and union all before . you might get a situation where these will not be in order so to avoid that you can add one seq col in all 3 select queries and hard code to 1 for first , 2 for 2nd and 3 for 3rd. then in you BCP you can put order by seq .

Comment: I’m using this for a money field:
Cast(RESIDUAL_TOTAL_AMT as MONEY) RESIDUAL_TOTAL_AMT, 

However, when I export with BCP I get the following error:
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax.

Comment: You have to convert everything in varchar as you are going to have it union all with header and metadata.